# How to make user profiles editable by site administrators

Tags: 7, workflows, nodes, users

For a site I'm building, Profile2 is not an option because it doesn't play with Pathauto. As an alternative, I want to extend the regular user profiles with a mugshot and a bio text field. I don't want the profile owners to have exclusive editing rights over those two extra fields; site administrators should be able to enter the profiles and edit the image and the text as required. Out of the box, this isn't workable because an administrator would need to override the user's password to make any changes to a profile, thus effectively issuing a new password for every change made. Is there a way to give administrators regular editing access to the profiles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can add the fields to the user entity at

*admin/config/people/accounts/fields*

While I think you can save the account form without updating the user password (don't enter a value for password when saving), if you want to move the password to a separate tab, you can use the module

[password_tab](https://drupal.org/project/password_tab)

Comment: It looks like I got confused by the browser's auto-completion of the 'password' field, and, as you suggest, administrators can in fact edit profiles. Thanks!